# Limitar carga de datos al filtrar con Angular e IONIC

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, filtro

Hola chicos estoy haciendo una app con angular usando el framework IONIC y estoy intentando que al escribir el nombre de la empresa, se filtre segun lo introducido. Eso ya lo he conseguido, el problema es que me carga de inicio todos los datos de la base de datos, y se ralentiza de manera inviable. ¿Hay alguna forma de que me vaya buscando las coincidencias pero que se muestren de cinco en cinco? Muchas gracias compañer@s.

Este es el pipe para filtrar.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filtro'
})
export class FiltroPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(arr: any[], texto: string, columna: string): any[] {

     if( texto === ''){
      return;
    } 
    
   
    texto = texto.toLowerCase();   

   return arr.filter(item =>{
     if(item[columna] != null)
      return item[columna].toLowerCase().includes(texto);  

      
    })
```

Y esta la implementacion en el html

```
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <input type="text" formControlName="company"  matInput
                      [matAutocomplete]="auto" (input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)">
                  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                      <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customers|  filtro: textSearch:'name'"
                       [value]="customer.name" (onSelectionChange)="selectCustomer(customer)">
                          {{customer.name}}
                      </mat-option>
                  </mat-autocomplete>
              </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Para lograr eso se debe modificar la API para que soporte la paginación de lo contrario no es posible hacerlo desde Angular.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta, la paginacion ya esta hecha, lo que no se es porque no pagina me debe faltar algun metodo o alguna cosa en Angular. Yo quiero que aparezcan 5 resultados y se vayan modificando segun lo que introduzca, pero siempre 5 resultados. Estoy seguro que es una chorrada pero no doy para más ya.

Comment: Te recomiendo primero hacer pruebas de paginación solamente usando la API con una herramienta como Postman. Cuando ya entiendas como obtener los resultados paginados entonces puedes hacer la adaptación en Angular.

Comment: Lobos te refieres a que me salga la tipica pagina con un "siguiente" para "paginar"? No se si entendiste eso. Yo lo que hago es buscar una empresa que me carga de la base de datos pero la base de datos tiene 3000 registros y cuando voy a escribir para buscar una, busca sobre los 3000 pero cargandolos todos. Podría ser que aparezcan 5 empresas y conforme vaya escribiendo se modifiquen los resultafos en base a lo que escribo. Creo que no tiene que ver con la paginacion. Yo uso el metodo slice(0,5)  y al escribir la primera letra salen coincidencia pero si sigo escribiendo ya no hace la busqueda.